# Importing Blender to 3DS Max

Tags: 3ds-max, import, blender

I'm trying to import a character I made to 3DS Max but each time I do the angle comes out really weird. How do I orient my object in Blender so it imports upright in 3DSM?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This might be better suited to the [Blender Stack Exchange site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). If you want to move it, you can flag the question for the attention of the moderators who will migrate it for you.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it best to ask this question here because most if not all users here work with 3DS Max and might know how to import into the program whereas Blender users primarily use Blender and probably aren't familiar with exporting to 3DS Max.

Comment: I don't think _most_ users here work with 3DS Max, I'd say it's easier to assume Blender users are more familiar with 3D workflows and file exchange. I don't think it's off-topic here but I suspect you might get better answers on the Blender SE.

Comment: What format are you using for interchange?